# Can we check in Apex code whether a particular profile has access on a class or Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, profile

Can we check in Apex code whether a profile has a permission on a particular class or page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this information is not visible in the API. If a user does not have access to a page or class, they will not be able to execute the code or view the page, as the system will prevent access preemptively.